# Qual è il significato di "schizzare" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Ecco il titolo di una notizia che ho letto su Euronews: ["Petizione anti Brexit, **schizzano** a oltre 2 milioni le firme"](http://it.euronews.com/2016/06/26/petizione-anti-brexit-schizzano-a-oltre-2-milioni-le-firme/). Non capisco il senso del verbo "schizzare" in questa espressione. Il significato figurato che ho trovato sul [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/schizzare/)

> riferito a persona, esprimere con vivacità o in modo evidente un sentimento, una condizione morale o fisica, attraverso lo sguardo o con l’atteggiamento, le parole, i modi

non sembra avere senso in questo contesto. Sapreste spiegarmi cosa vuol dire "**schizzano** a oltre 2 milioni le firme"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In questo caso, il verbo "schizzare" è riferito al "numero di firme" e ha i seguenti significati:

> *estens.* Balzare, saltare via di scatto: il tappo dello spumante è schizzato contro il lampadario; al suono del campanello schizzò dal letto. ([Dizionari - la Repubblica](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/S/schizzare.php))
>
> *estens.*, di qcs., essere proiettato con forza, per lo più verso l’alto: lapilli incandescenti schizzano dalla bocca del vulcano ([Dizionario italiano - De Mauro](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/schizzare))

*i.e.* il numero di firme è balzato (di scatto, rapidamente) oltre "2 milioni", cioè, ha superato rapidamente i 2 milioni.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE!

Comment: Please, note that  here we have the policy of answering in English to a question posted in English and in Italian to a question posted in Italian, so you should write your answer entirely in Italian.

Comment: @Charo ok, ho tradotto la risposta in italiano.

Comment: Suppongo che si tratti di qualcosa di figurato perché le firme non balzano né sono proiettate via con forza. Potresti chiarirlo nella tua risposta?

Comment: @Charo, ovviamente lo è. Come in Inglese potresti usare il verbo "to shoot" per esprimere esattamente lo stesso concetto di movimento rapido ed improvviso anche se non carichi un fucile con le firme. Nella citazione dai dizionari è inclusa l'abbreviazione *estens.*

Comment: @ErikvanDoren: A essere (eccessivamente) pignoli quell'“estens.” si riferisce al fatto che non si parla – come nell'accezione fondamentale – di liquidi, bensì di altri oggetti, ma pur sempre concreti (tappi, persone, lapilli). Che un numero di firme “schizzi” è effettivamente un uso figurato, non esemplificato in quelle voci di dizionario, ma possibile per praticamente qualunque parola.

Comment: @ErikvanDoren: Quindi, significa una crescita molto rapida del numero di firme?

Comment: @AlessioCantarella: Quindi, significa una crescita molto rapida del numero di firme?

Comment: @Charo esatto: significa che il numero di firme ha superato rapidamente i 2 milioni.

Comment: @AlessioCantarella: Potresti aggiungerlo alla risposta?

Comment: @Charo già fatto!

Comment: @DaG, *estens.* non e' l'abbreviazione di estensivo/estensione? Per intendere: allargare il significato di un vocabolo per indicare oggetti **o idee** affini? Quali sono le regole per un dizionario riguardo l'uso di estens. e fig.?

Comment: Precisamente, @ErikvanDoren! Nel caso del De Mauro, per esempio, è [l'abbreviazione di “estensivo”](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/abbreviazioni), “che estende, che allarga un uso, un significato al di là di quello proprio” (sempre dal [De Mauro](http://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/estensivo)) qui per dire che un termine che alla lettera si applica a un liquido si può usare anche per tappi e lapilli. Giustamente, “fig.” indica poi un'applicazione ad ambiti non concreti.

Comment: @DaG, esatto, a me fu insegnato che "per estensione" (treccani per esempio usa quella) non riguarda solo allargare il significato ad altri oggetti ma anche idee: come *schizzare* sarebbe per l'idea di movimento rapido ed improvviso. In senso figurato sarebbe in usi tipo "occhi che schizzano fuori dalle orbite", o no?

Comment: Può darsi benissimo, ma in tal caso non so che differenza facciano fra “estens.” e “fig.” i lessicografi che – come De Mauro – usano queste due marche. Ma stiamo facendo delle distinzioni veramente bizantine! :-)